# Oracle subqueries with Join - how to refer to subquery column?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables, Project and Project_Property with a 1 to many from Project to Project_Property. I'm trying to use subqueries to get three properties by Project and join on Project ("Repo" in the example). Caveat: I'm primarily a SQL Server guy so I'm trying to take what I know works in SQL and project it into Oracle.

I wrote this:

```
select s1.Repo, s1.Solution, p1.Project, a1.Assembly
from
(
    select p.name as "Repo", pp.value as "Solution"
    from project p join project_property pp on p.id=pp.project_id
    where pp.name='mssolutionname'
) s1 join
(
    select p.name as "Repo", pp.value as "Project"
    from project p join project_property pp on p.id=pp.project_id
    where pp.name='msprojectname'
) p1 on p1.Repo=s1.Repo join
(
    select p.name as "Repo", pp.value as "Assembly"
    from project p join project_property pp on p.id=pp.project_id
    where pp.name='msassemblyname'
) a1 on s1.Repo=a1.Repo;
```

But when I run it I get:

```
ORA-00904: "S1"."REPO": invalid identifier
```

Is there a different format for this type of query in Oracle? How do I reference the values selected in the subqueries in the outer, main query, particularly with respect to JOINing the subqueries. Or do I just have a typo I missed. Wouldn't be the first time.

TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you alias columns using double quotes, then the column name becomes case sensitive.  Since you coded `p.name as "Repo"`, the column **must** be referred to as `si."Repo"`.  If you leave off the double quotes (`p.name as repo`), then you can refer to it in a case-insensitive manner (`si.repo`, `si.Repo`, or `si.rEPo`)

Comment: Something I didn't know, however, in the code above I'm consistent in my casing in all references to the column aliases, am I not?

Comment: However, removing the double-quotes did fix the problem. Learn something new every day. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are, but in oracle you have to use the aliases as you create then, so as in your query using **s1."Repo"** it would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you already accept the previous answer, I would suggest you to change your sql to this. It would be more performatic

```
select 
    p.name as Repo, 
    case when pp.name='mssolutionname' then pp.value else null end as Solution,
    case when pp.name='msprojectname' then pp.value else null end as Project,
    case when pp.name='msassemblyname' then pp.value else null end as Assembly
from 
    project p,
    project_property pp
where 
    p.id=pp.project_id
```

Comment: There's a reason for the WHERE clauses in each subquery and the way the subqueries are JOINed. We have thousands of entries in the Projects table but only maybe 20% have the "mssolutionname" property. Of that only 10% have the "msassemblyname" property. I'd have to add a lot of code to the WHERE clause to make the above work, or else wrap it in an outer query that drops all the null entries, which is most of them. I probably could improve the execution plan by moving the A1 subquery to be first since that's the smallest result set, but the whole thing runs in milliseconds...